# gnuplot: modify matrix before plotting

Tags: gnuplot

I normally plot a `n x n` matrix in gnuplot by using

`plot "data.log" matrix with image`

Now I want to do use the `abs()` or `log()` function to modify the matrix. How is that possible?

Comment: plot "data.log" matrix using 1:2:(abs($3)) with image

Comment: @MichaelO. Great! But why does it work?

Comment: Why shoudn't it work? See `help matrix`.

Comment: @MichaelO. I thought that 1:2 for example only accesses the first two columns. But my matrix has 100. So I don't see why it works. I will look it up